# How would I generate a pulsating effect on an image that is to be drawn inside of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```
    var testPhoto = new Image();
    testPhoto.src = "http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/img/9logo.jpg"
    testPhoto.className = "pulse";
```

and then:

```
    topSlice.drawImage(testPhoto, 100, 200, 40, 40);
```

It appears the pulsating effect doesn't work after drawing the image, how should I fix this? [I'm following this tutorial for the pulsating effect.](http://cssdeck.com/labs/simple-css3-heart-pulsing-animations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead and work with blend modes / alpha blending:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = new Image();


image.src = "http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/img/9logo.jpg";

function update(timestamp) {
  
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.globalAlpha = Math.sin(timestamp/100) * 0.5 + 0.5;
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```